# jQuery 1.9.1 Unable to get property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined or null reference Line 5823

Tags: jquery

Recently I updated my ASP.Net MVC4 project to upgrade to jQuery 1.9.1. But since then I am getting a strange error as soon as any page is loaded:

(Chrome) jquery-1.9.1.js:5823 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of null

(IE10) Unable to get property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined or null reference 
jquery-1.9.1.js, line 5823 character 3

The 'document' parameter being passed to its parent function createSafeFragment( document ) is always null. The error is persistent in IE10 as well as Chrome. Below is how scripts are included in the layout:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I tried to trace the error by debugging the scripts but could not find the exact source.

Has anybody come across this with any breakthrough? Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE

---

jQuery Tooltip was conflicting with Bootstrap Tooltip.
Changed the functionality to use Bootstrap and the error has gone.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery's migrate plugin? http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin

Comment: Is there any code related to this? (other than what is in the core)

Comment: @j08691 - I did try jQuery migrate 1.1.1 but it was generating few more warning messages and the error was still there.

Comment: @ Kevin B - I was using modernizr-2.6.2.js but removed just to check. Didn't make any difference. There is one more page specific js at the end but I didn't find any issue debugging it.

Comment: @Santosh why you not validate my answer ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have simply a conflict between bootstrap and jQuery UI tooltips features.

You can't use booth tooltips feature on the same display. For any choose one and go to customize the other to remove tooltips feature. Remove all other duplicated none-useful features (not useful to use dialog from JQUI or BT too). Download the modified package and replace the .js file in your js directory.

Unchecked unneeded features from : [Boostrap customize package](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html) or [jQuery UI customize package](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: That did it for me. I found $(document).tooltip(); in my javascript. Removing that fixed the error.

Comment: @KJPrice yes but this is not necessary to use booth lib with boot tooltip possibilities, it's better to choose one.

Comment: A stray $(document).tooltip(); in my javascript caused this error, as KJ Price mentions above.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to remove `$(document).tooltip();`. Probably you are intending to use jQuery ui tooltip instead of Bootstrap tooltip. Use these lines to revert Bootstrap override:

```js
// return $.fn.tooltip to previously assigned value
var bootstrapTooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();

// give $().bootstrapTooltip the Bootstrap functionality
$.fn.bootstrapTooltip = bootstrapTooltip

// now activate tooltip plugin from jQuery ui
$(document).tooltip();
```

Alternatively, make sure you are including `bootstrap.js` **before** jquery ui. That will also take care of priority.

Comment: I use bootstraps tooltips on some pages that share the bs file with one that uses jqueryUI tooltips making it impractical for me to modify the bootstrap lib to exclude the tooltip function. This was a perfect solution for my use.