# Drupal, Bootstrap and Jquery conflict?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7

Someone asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790568/jquery-1-9-1-unable-to-get-property-createdocumentfragment-of-undefined-or-nul), but it doesn't solve my problem, although it describes it pretty well. I am using

- Drupal 7
- Jquery 1.10
- Bootstrap 3.0.2

When I do this:

```
<a href="#whatever">Click me</a>
```

It doesn't go to the part on the page where it's supposed to. Instead it throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null
```

I've tried disabling the tooltip feature of Bootstrap. Doesn't work. I have no idea why it would do this on these types of links. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

All the scripts I have included on that page:

```
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="/www/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2"></script>
<script src="/www/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script src="/www/misc/drupal.js?nizv5b"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/www/sites/all/modules/codefilter/codefilter.js?nizv5b"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/sorting/alt-string.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/sorting/currency.js"></script>
<script src="/www/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?nizv5b"></script>
```

Comment: What code is invoked when you click the link? Do you have a jQuery handler? Bootstrap? Does Drupal include other jQuery libraries?

Comment: I included a list of all the JS files that get included on that page. There is no tooltip feature. I thought perhaps I'm including Bootstrap twice, but the last bootstrap.js file, as per the description in the file, says: "Provides general enhancements and fixes to Bootstrap's JS files". So that looks like it's part of the bootstrap module and theme.

Comment: How can I see what is invoked when I click the link? Right now I have nothing attaching to the event (the event being clicking on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find [some help here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2291451). However, I don't want to use an unstable version, so I just kind of "cheated" and remove the lines that cause the problem. I.e. in bootstrap.js I removed:

```
var $fakeAnchor = $('<div/>')
   .addClass('element-invisible')
   .attr(attr, $target.attr(attr))
   .css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: offset + 'px',
      zIndex: -1000
   })
   .appendTo(document);
```

And this:

```
$fakeAnchor.remove();
```

Solves the problem, but not sure what side effects would be there. But I do think this can be closed as it's too "localized"

Answer (score 1):

Can be disabled from UI instead : https://www.drupal.org/node/2466151

```
Home » Administration » Appearance » Settings » Bootstrap (or your enabled Bootstrap-subtheme » Javascript » Anchors
```

**Upgrading to 7.x-3.1-beta3 fixed it for me and kept the smooth scrolling  ability.**